# Getting a better CPU-based OpenCL driver (OS X)

Tags: macos, opencl, intel

While browsing the Web, I came across this page from the PyOpenCL project:
[Py OpenCL Mac OS Install Readme](https://documen.tician.de/pyopencl/misc.html)

On this page, something strange is alleged:
"OS X has support for both CPU- and GPU-based OpenCL built in. Unfortunately, the built-in drivers can be temperamental, and they have not advanced as quickly as one might like. To make PyOpenCL use a more up-to-date (and open-source) CPU-based OpenCL driver, type the following:

conda install osx-pocl-opencl pocl (OS X)

Note that, by installing osx-pocl-opencl, you will no longer be able to use PyOpenCL to talk to the system-wide Apple OpenCL drivers. To regain access to those drivers, simply uninstall osx-pocl-opencl and reinstall pyopencl afterwards."

Is this true? Are there faster OpenCL drivers for MacOS?
I'm not interested in installing PyOpenCL. Is there a way for me to get my hands on those "faster" drivers?

Comment: As an aside, Apple wants you to forget about OpenGL, OpenCL, Vulcan or anything else Khronos and not Apple. All things are handled by Metal, says Apple.

Comment: Vulkan works pretty well through the MoltenVk layer, and CL isn't going to magically stop working. BUT, it's certainly not recommended for new development. Have a look at Metal. Or write your app in Unity, use compute shaders and let their compiler figure it out for you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that they're suggesting you use [pocl](http://portablecl.org/), an open source OpenCL implementation with support for OpenCL 1.2 features (and some 2.0 features). I can't comment on the performance, but it's definitely true that the official Mac OS OpenCL drivers are pretty finicky.

I found [this readme](https://github.com/pocl/pocl/blob/master/README.OSX) detailing the steps to build and install pocl for OSX.

Comment: I cannot accept this as a final answer, as the provided installation steps don't work on my Mac OS X Lion. Also, thanks Mr Ken WHITE: I didn't know I could comment again.

Comment: @N.Wells I can't help you troubleshoot the issue if you just say "the steps don't work".

Comment: Sorry for the lack of details, but I couldn't get hwloc to install on Mac OS X Lion with or without MacPorts. That's the show stopper, here.

Comment: Have you tried the second set of instructions using Homebrew?

Comment: Homebrew on Mac OS X Lion, does not see hwloc (No formula for hwloc). I guess my only option is to upgrade my OS.

Comment: Looking at [the metadata](https://formulae.brew.sh/api/formula/hwloc.json), it looks like the minimum version supported is El Capitan (10.11).

Comment: your link doesn't work anymore. don't post links in your answers